# Git Pull from Shell script

Tags: git, bash, shell

I'm trying to update a git repo from a bash script and I've run into some trouble.  I can run `git pull` and have it work if there is no other lines or characters after the git pull but if I say have

```
#!/bin/bash
git pull
echo "test"
```

then I get

```
' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Did you mean this?
        pull
```

in the terminal instead of it actually doing the `git pull`.

Comment: Does that file have DOS newlines? Does running `dos2unix` on that script help?

Comment: use apt-get install git if you have UNIX based system, install git manually if you have window based system.

Comment: As @EtanReisner suggested, you make actually be running `git pull\r`.

Comment: @Ioan They clearly have git installed as they are getting an error message from git.

Answer (score 3):

You have to do **dos2unix**  first like Etan mentioned. I can regenerate the same error if I do the reverse (i.e. unix2dos)

**$ cat 1.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

git pull
echo ----
```

**$ ./1.sh**

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount parent /cygdrive)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
----
```

See above, git pull command worked but with a valid error message that no repo mentioned after pull as im doing first time. That means git exists (if you do **which git** you'll see valid git executable location).

**$ unix2dos.exe ./1.sh**

```
unix2dos: converting file ./1.sh to DOS format ...
```

Now, my file is in DOS format (and Im running the script in Linux machine). Are you using Cygwin?

**$ ./1.sh**

```
./1.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found
' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Did you mean this?
        pull
----
```

OK, convert it back to Unix line ending chars using dos2unix

**$ dos2unix.exe ./1.sh**

```
dos2unix: converting file ./1.sh to Unix format ...
```

**$ ./1.sh**

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount parent /cygdrive)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
----
```

It works as expected.

OR try running with **bash -x**